# How to change a value of a pixel

Tags: image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

The RGB value in (x,y)=(237,278) is (25,21,134). How do I change it to (244, 10, 15)?

```
pic = cv2.imread("apple.jpg")

plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbFQL.png)

Comment: this question shows no research effort. that would be expected though. please review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("apple.jpg")
pixel = image[237, 278]
image[237, 278] = [244, 10, 15]
cv2.imwrite('change.png', image)
```

Comment: The resulting value isn't correct. I will simplify my question to change the value of a pixel to (0,0,0). The resulting value will be (73,0,0). It won't be (0,0,0).

Comment: explain "not correct". this question looks trivial, the answer is expectedly trivial. this can't possibly be wrong. your issue is likely using lossy compression and not realizing.

Comment: Could you please explain deeply?